# How to switch ngx-markdown theme dynamically?

Tags: angular, markdown, themes, prismjs

I have an Angular app that can switch between light and dark theme.

I use `ngx-markdown` and display code blocks with `prism.js` for language highlighting.

I imported 2 themes in `package.json`

```json
"styles": [
    [...],
    "node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-vs.css",
    "node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-vsc-dark-plus.css"
],
```

How can I change `Prism.js` theme dynamically with Typescript ?